# Tensorlow model cant predict and the only thing i get is errormessage

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I tryed for Days to get this model to predict some output but the only thing I got is this error message

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\hahnt\PycharmProjects\6outof49\speechkeybourd\Include\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2440, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\hahnt\PycharmProjects\6outof49\speechkeybourd\Include\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2425, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\hahnt\PycharmProjects\6outof49\speechkeybourd\Include\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2413, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\hahnt\PycharmProjects\6outof49\speechkeybourd\Include\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2381, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\hahnt\PycharmProjects\6outof49\speechkeybourd\Include\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\hahnt\PycharmProjects\6outof49\speechkeybourd\Include\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 253, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

the model looks likew this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(units=59, input_shape=[None, 59]),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=49, activation='softmax'),
])


model.summary()

model.compile(loss="mse",
              optimizer='adam',
              )
```

Maybe some one also got this error message before and can help me with it.